# Ошибка подключения к бд 10061 MySQL

Tags: mysql, база-данных

Установил MySQL, зашел в воркбенч, создал бд. После перезагрузки ПК появилась ошибка [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: пароль неправильный

Comment: Вы установили и запустили MySQL но не установили как службу, по этому, после перезагрузки ПК вам снова нужно запустить MySQL, поищите ярлык запуска в Пуске